# Laravel 5.4 - Task scheduler withoutOverlapping() Running locally, but not on server

Tags: php, laravel

I have set up tasks on kernel.php. I have set up a similar debian environment locally, and the tasks are running as expected. However, on the server, tasks are not running if withoutOverlapping() method is given. If withoutOverlapping() is not given, tasks are running as expected.

Current configuration on kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('perform:task_one')->withoutOverlapping()->everyFiveMinutes();
```

Task is not fired at all. If I remove withoutOverlapping, task is fired. 
I have implemented withoutOverlapping as my task involves some mailing and may consume time at instances.

Comment: your schedule is working correctly on the prod server without withoutOverlapping, please?

Comment: Check if Maintenance is Off or On, if on add `->evenInMaintenanceMode();`

Comment: Do you have any files in your `storage/framework` folder?

Comment: @Froxz, Not in maintenance mode

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih, Not working on prod server.

Comment: @Jerodev,  No files found in storage/framework. I just got cache, session and views folders.

Comment: @Dilani have you added the Cron entry to your prod server, please, if not you should do that. check Starting The Scheduler section within https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling to do that

Comment: I have added the cron entry on prod server. Cron job is running if I remove withoutOverlapping().